# Google autocomplete places api giving an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

`enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/saisoft00/s2rcerxz/

input:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=AIzaSyB1xO0ksjZhlpmBPSovLvKjbDXUn2gOYjg&types=geocode&input=mil&_=1489747038346. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://isa4p.com' is therefore not allowed access.

i know this is an old error but i tried to solve it by googling i followed some nothing worked for me so can anyone suggest best solution.

Comment: can you check this? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359730/google-place-api-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-req](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359730/google-place-api-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-req)

Comment: no i have tried with jsonp in that case json is broken and it gives me an error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :)@JaydeepMarvaniya