# XMLHttpRequest cannot load No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' Google maps

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to React js I am trying to simple dynamically changing map with respected to user input But for specific place seach request this error rises

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=undef…ined&radius=1000&keyword=fdtbf&key=myapikey.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

this is my node js code

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

//Import To Pord
import api from './routes/api';
import auth from './routes/auth'
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import {LoginCheck} from './middleware/authCheck';
import cors from 'cors';


//All Webpack Stuff
import webpackConfig from '../../webpack.config.dev';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware'
import webpackHotMidleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';


//Server Side Rendering Stuff
import {match, RouterContext  } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { dispatch } from 'redux';
import { renderToString, renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server';
import reducer from '../../src/client/Reducers';
import routes from '../client/routes';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore ,applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import React from 'react'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import serialize from 'serialize-javascript';


//PassPort Stuff Import This




let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'))


const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
    hot: true,
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    noInfo: true
}));

app.use(webpackHotMidleware(compiler));



app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser('sdkhcvlsd684684JJJklvblsdkuvgblsduvblsidvksdjbvlsjvuywlsfvliusdgv'));
//Check Auth MiddleWare
app.use(LoginCheck)
//Passport Api
app.use('/auth',auth);
//Our Api
app.use('/p',api);



app.get('/*', (req, res,next) => {

    // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../index.html'))
    // Server Side Rendering Starts
    match({routes:routes(),location:req.url},(err,redirectLocation,renderProps) => {
        if (err) return next(err);


        if (redirectLocation) {
            return res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
        }

        // if (!renderProps) {
        //     res.redirect('/404')
        // }

        const components = renderProps.components;

        const Comp = components[components.length - 1].WrappedComponent;

        const fetchData = (Comp && Comp.fetchData) || (() => Promise.resolve())

        const initialState = {}

        const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));


        const { location, params, history } = renderProps

        fetchData({ store, location, params, history }).then(() => {
            const body = renderToString(
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
                </Provider>
            )

            const state = store.getState();
            // console.log(state)


            let head = Helmet.rewind();
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
            res.send(`<!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
            <head>
               ${head.title}
                ${head.meta}
                ${head.link}
            </head>
            <body>
              <div id="app" >${body}</div>
              <script>window.__STATE__=${JSON.stringify(state)}</script>

              <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
            </body>
          </html>`)
        })
            .catch((err) => next(err))



    })
});


app.listen(3000 ,() => {
    console.log('Listening')
});
```

this is my axios request

```
export function getPlaceFromCoords(term,coords) {
    // https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=13.0826802,80.2707184&radius=500&keyword=parks&key=AIzaSyAZbur2hq7p3UxjYrA2_G4ctpswFi0pO3A
    console.log(coords)
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${coords.lat},${coords.lng}&radius=1000&keyword=${term}&key=${config.MAP_API}`).then(response => {
            return response.data
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Ask the backend guy to implement CORS. Nothing to do with react.

Comment: I used this middle ware **app.use(cors());** But no use

Comment: You need to check that properly. But it is all backend stuff. No Reactjs issue.

Comment: Possibly already answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359730/google-place-api-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-req

Comment: Possibly axios doesn't support jsonp @ToddChaffee

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors may relate to getting proper access

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CORS headers are not set for Places API web service on Google backend servers. So you won't be able to call Places API web service from the client side JavaScript code due to the Same-Origin policy of the browsers.

In order to use Places on client side JavaScript you have to use a Places library of Google Maps JavaScript API. The places library has nearby, radar and text search functionality very similar to the corresponding web service.

For further details please have a look at the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Hope it helps!

Comment: then what does the google console dashboard web browser referrer section is for?

Comment: Where's the part in the linked doc that talks about having to use the Javascript API for access from browser?