# Failed to load google place API

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

Failed to load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=12.938008,77.5790956&radius=100000&rankBy=prominence&keyword=visiting+places=near+me&key=AIzaSyAdLYQ6qjosGg82jMH2jymB6XS_tWRKHpE: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I am getting error in console but in network its showing successful response.enter image description here

Comment: On your `google developer console` where you obtained the `API key`, you have to enter `localhost:3000` as one of the `HTTP referrers`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' Google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294257/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on)