# CORS issue with JavaScript accessing google places API

Tags: google-maps

Tried multiple combinations with header to do a ajax jQuery call to [google maps Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) to get the predictions.

I get following error:

> Failed to load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Amsterdam&types=geocode&key=AIzaSyBqYrYm377wh0pgINHBQfadjCokJkj_uVQ&_=1535634162773:
>
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
>   Origin 'https://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.

while executing following code here in console (without the API Key in the URL):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Amsterdam&types=geocode&key={API Key Here}",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    "crossDomain": true,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description, x-requested-with, x-requested-by',
        "accept": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
    },
    success: postSuccess,
    error: postError,
});
function postSuccess(result,status,xhr) {
    console.log("postSuccess");
}
function postError(xhr,status,error) {
    console.log("postError", xhr,status,error);
}
```

Would be great if someone can point me towards the resolution.

Edit: Searched for similar questions before asking one, found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359730/google-place-api-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-req?rq=1) but solution was not helpful.

Edit2: To be more specific, I would like to retrieve the JSON result from Places API in JavaScript: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Amsterdam&types=geocode&key={API Key Here}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the places API from javascript use the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places).

Comment: turns out, there was an IP restriction in the google console due to which my calls did not work.